# Reading value from registry

Tags: c#, .net, registry

google is not helping me today, so i need your help. Is there a possible way to read a value from a registry ? example this location --> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > MyKey the column is Test key

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey?

Comment: I've decided to help you with your Google-Fu - it could use some improvement.
https://www.google.com/search?q=read+registry+values+csharp

Comment: You need 15 [rep](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) to up/down vote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

64bit + 32bit

```
   using Microsoft.Win32;
    public static string GetRegistry()
    {
        string registryValue = string.Empty;
        RegistryKey localKey = null;
        if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
        {
            localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
        }
        else
        {
            localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);
        }

        try
        {
            localKey = localKey.OpenSubKey(@"Software\\MyKey");
            registryValue = localKey.GetValue("TestKey").ToString();
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException nre)
        {

        }
        return registryValue;
    }
```

Comment: Nice that you give such a complete answer - personally I'd refactor that a little since the only code affected by your `if` is the value of `RegistryView.Registry32`/`64`.

Comment: I agree with Mr. Puzey. Furthermore, If "MyKey" does not exist in registry, or the read fails for some other reason, then localKey will be null and you'll get an exception. A try/catch statement should be used here.

Answer (score 0):

rtry this:

```
static object GetRegistryValue(string fullPath, object defaultValue)
{
    string keyName = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
    string valueName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
    return Registry.GetValue(keyName, valueName, defaultValue);
}
```

or you you can use `Registry.LocalMachine`
go through this http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/01/registry-ins-and-outs-using-c/

Answer (score 0):

example in code project :

[Read, write and delete from registry with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C)

[All (you wanted to know) about the Registry with C#, Part 1 of 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4808/All-you-wanted-to-know-about-the-Registry-with-C-P)

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
...

RegistryKey masterKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(
            "SOFTWARE\\Test\\Preferences");
if (masterKey == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Null Masterkey!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine ("MyKey = {0}", masterKey.GetValue ("MyKey"));
}
masterKey.Close();
```